# Jira  attachment limitation on file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, jira

We use Jira as our bug and task tracker. Because of file number limitation (a single folder can only contain limited number of files --I must say we are not out of space) on Linux, we need to move the old issue's attachments to another folder so that new files couldn be attached if the number of attachment reach the limit, but in these case, if people want to get old attachment, as Jira admin, we need to get that file on sever manually.

do you have any idea that can solve this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to directly contact Jira about the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, the limit is from Jira or from the Linux fs?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If so; please post it here.